# combobox auto complete any string occurrence

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I'm using a ComboBox featuring auto complete. This code is being used:

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

`DataSource`'s `items` is a `List<String>.` Assuming I have a list of names (like *John May*), searching for *May* will not show the `ComboBox` item "John May". Instead, I have to enter "John" for *John May* to be displayed.

What do I need to adjust so that the entire `ComboBox` entry is searched instead of just the first part of the string?
I'm looking forward to seeing some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible to perform a *contains*-like string matching using the built in functionality. From the [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Use the AutoCompleteCustomSource, AutoCompleteMode, and
>   AutoCompleteSource properties to create a ComboBox that automatically
>   completes input strings **by comparing the prefix being entered to the
>   prefixes of all strings in a maintained source**.

[This post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ebaaed0-cd29-4663-9a43-973729d66cea/autocomplete-combobox-match-any-part-of-string-not-only-beginning-string?forum=winforms) suggests handling this functionality manually by reacting to key press events.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't get along with that.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't perform such operations with an *autocomplete* class. Instead you can create your custom source with data table. Data table allows to search words with "Like" function.

1. Create data table as a main table (Don't change the data of this table while typing in combo box).
2. Load your list to the table
3. perform search operations.
4. Perform filter operations and load your filtered results in temporary table.
5. Set temporary table as customer source of combo box.

For clear answer check this [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4ebaaed0-cd29-4663-9a43-973729d66cea/autocomplete-combobox-match-any-part-of-string-not-only-beginning-string?forum=winforms).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the first [referenced MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4ebaaed0-cd29-4663-9a43-973729d66cea/autocomplete-combobox-match-any-part-of-string-not-only-beginning-string?forum=winforms) to work Mitja Bonca and the second option by Pouya Lariyan didn't work straight off for me ( I think it relies on the items being set in the UI. So with credit I'm positng the code I adapted from Pouya'

usage

```
autoCompleteCmb = new AutoCompleteCombobox();
autoCompleteCmb.SelectedIndexChanged += selectedIndexChanged;
this.Controls.Add(autoCompleteCmb );
var listTest = new List<string> { "Paul", "Pauline", "Daniel" };
listTest.ForEach(i=> {autoCompleteCmb.Items.Add(i)});
```

UserControl AutoCompleteCombobox.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyNamespace
{
public partial class AutoCompleteCombobox : ComboBox
{
    public AutoCompleteCombobox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public IList<object> m_collectionList = null;


    public AutoCompleteCombobox(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
    }

    protected override void OnTextUpdate(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_collectionList == null)
        {
            m_collectionList = this.Items.OfType<object>().ToList();
        }

        IList<object> values = m_collectionList
            .Where(x => x.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Text.ToLower()))
            .ToList<object>();

        this.Items.Clear();
        this.Items.AddRange(this.Text != string.Empty ? values.ToArray() : m_collectionList.ToArray());

        this.SelectionStart = this.Text.Length;
        this.DroppedDown = true;
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text != string.Empty) return;
        this.Items.Clear();
        this.Items.AddRange(m_collectionList.ToArray());
    }

  }
}
```